# htmlspecialchars converting apostrophe to &amp;#039; for facebook og:title tag

Tags: php, facebook, metadata, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I'm having a slight struggle with the og:title tag on my website. Whenever an article title has an apostrophe and gets shared on Facebook, `&#039;` shows up instead of the apostrophe. I've compared my meta tags to a friend's site that successfully shows his apostrophes and the only difference I can find is this:

Code for apostrophes placed in the og:title for my site:
    `&amp;#039;`

Code for apostrophes placed in the og:title for friend's site:
    `&#039;`

I think my site is converting the ampersand after having already converted the apostrophe, and that is making it show up as `&#039;` on Facebook.

I'm using K2 for Joomla!, and have asked this question on their forums but I haven't received a single reply in 5 days now.

This is the code I found in the com_k2>views>item>view.html.php file:

```
$document->setMetaData('og:title', htmlspecialchars($document->getTitle(), ENT_QUOTES,  'UTF-8'));
```

I'm not php savvy, is there any way I can change this so the code will show up right?
If it helps, here's a [link](http://sciality.com/the-feed/einstein-s-relativity-still-holds-true.html) to an article with an apostrophe in the title from the site.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation for htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and look at the description of when it will convert the single quote (often used as an apostrophe). It will only encode the single-quote if `ENT_QUOTES` is set, and you have set `ENT_QUOTES` in your invocation of htmlspecialchars.

If you don't want the single-quote to be encoded then you simply need to stop using that flag and switch it for `ENT_COMPAT` (which encodes double-quote but not single-quote), so that your statement becomes:

```
$document->setMetaData('og:title',
        htmlspecialchars($document->getTitle(),
        ENT_COMPAT,  'UTF-8'));
```

(I've added the line breaks so it's easy to read on this page, but don't add line breaks in your actual code.)

Also note that htmlspecialchars has a final, optional parameter (added in PHP 5.2.3) called **double_encode**. It defaults to `true`, but if you set this parameter to `false` then PHP will not encode existing entities, so even if you did encode the single-quote, the resulting `&#039;` would not be further encoded to `&amp;#039;` by further invocations of htmlspecialchars, it would be left as `&#039;`.