# Page Title showing ASCII character

Tags: php, joomla

am using below to show browser page title on a joomla website. The only issue occurs when there are apostrophe in the title.

```
$browserpagetitle= 'My site - '.$this->item->title;
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle($browserpagetitle);
```

If the item title is Apple's. it will show : `My site - Apple&#39;s`

I have tried :

```
$browserpagetitle= 'My site - '.$this->item->title;
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
echo html_entity_decode($document->setTitle($browserpagetitle), ENT_QUOTES);
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928717/my-webpage-display-039-and-not/29928961) but no luck

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Volunteers in this community may be able to give you resolving advice, but if you ask a community of volunteers who have an intimate understanding of Joomla and its extensions, you are FAR more likely to receive a Joomla-specific answer that considers best practices within the scope of the CMS.

Comment: Another related SO page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16403858/2943403  Other related content from the web (some very old) https://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-it/48843-apostrophe-039-not-translate , https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=17256

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
$browserpagetitle= 'My site - '.$this->item->title;
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle(htmlspecialchars_decode($browserpagetitle,ENT_QUOTES));
```

Comment: Thanks but no change.

For info this is a joomla website

Comment: In my case it worked properly. See my updated code and see my output. https://prnt.sc/17tjzjw

Comment: Please confirm my updated code worked or not?

Comment: Am not sure what do you want me to confirm, for me your code is not working

Comment: Hi, sorry didn't see that you updated the codes.

Working perfectly now !

Comment: Hi,
however there is an issue with your code. With the initial code. I was able to load both Metatag Title and Browser Title. With your code it will load up browser title and will load content of my page as Metatag Title.

P.S. I can't upvote (seems I don't have enough reputation here)

Comment: 1. Please never say **Can you please give upvote** If your answer is worthy of an upvote, trust that people will do the right thing.  2. Please never post code-only answers -- these are low-value posts that miss an excellent opportunity to educate and empower the OP and thousands of future developers.  You are never only speaking to the OP when you post an answer.  3. Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them. If you think that you are the first person to advise `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, then you should search this site a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

immediately after your opening

```
<html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>*page title here*</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Am not a coder but these seems to be codes for a HTML webpage.

Comment: You're right. This is HTML code, because the caption is in the browser's. The browser understands HTML.